# Django CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN - how to change gracefully

Tags: django, cookies, django-csrf

I have a public Django site which uses CSRF protection.

I have not set the `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN`. My site uses subdomains.

Sometimes, a user ends up having a `csrftoken` cookie set on `.toplevel.com` as well as on `sub.toplevel.com`. This causes problems, as CSRF checking fails if the wrong cookie is used in the check.

I would like to set a `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN` to `.toplevel.com`. However, I would also like to delete any `csrftoken` cookies for any `*.toplevel.com` subdomains. How would I do this?

If I do not delete the other cookies, I will just end up in the original situation of having two cookies with the same name on different domains, which causes issues.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a similar problem. The way I dealt with it is together with `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN` I also changed the `CSRF_COOKIE_NAME`, making old `"csrftoken"` cookies obsolete.

Comment: the only downside is that it's not a very graceful approach (POST requests that come right after this new configuration will fail).

Comment: It's very true, if this change is made in between someone doing a GET  and then an immediate POST request, it will fail. It is a very unlikely case if there are not many users on site, but if does presents a big problem (if there are thousands of concurrent users for instance), it can be dealt with by temporarily overriding `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` and checking for both cookie names in `process_view` method.

Comment: @AlexeyKuleshevich can you help me with my problem too? http://stackoverflow.com/q/29559000/4029893. Seems like you would understand.