# Django csrf cookie not set for sub domain when accessed in iframe on third party site

Tags: django, cookies, cross-domain, django-csrf, cross-site

My app worked well so far, when all was done by accessing its public IP.

Now, it's being added to the main site, as app.mainsite.com.
It's accessible like that. I can log in, etc, everything.

But my app is a little special in that, a certain feature of it allows its users to open one of its URLs in an iframe on any third party site where the app's scripts are embedded in html, to do some app specific activity on those third party sites. Now, everyone could see the new stuff the app brought to those third party sites, but to change some settings as to how, one had to be logged in to my app. If not, one would be redirected inside the modal itself, and if login was successful, they'd be redirected to the settings edit page. Basically, any write requests from the third party sites, required the site owner to be logged in to our app. Either they could login inside the modal, or log in from another tab, and then refresh their site to be able to get inside the edit view.

The problem is, earlier, it all worked perfectly.
Now, I can do form post with csrf tokens from app.mainsite.com, but when it's opened in the iframe, it throws `CSRF cookie not set`.

I checked the Resources tab, and under that, the `csrftoken` in app.mainsite.com does not match the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` in the form.
Obviously thus, CSRF fails.

How can I overcome this?

I tried setting `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN='.mainsite.com'` but that didn't work.

What can I do?

Comment: I understand your problem, but I am not sure I can help without investigating how your app works exactly. I haven't had to deal with POST requests from within an iframe embedded into a third party site, but it seems like it should work just fine. I would start by going through `CsrfViewMiddleware` and investigating where exactly it fails: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/csrf.py#L76 Also `'.mainsite.com'` setting is for all subdomains, you should set it to: `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN='app.mainsite.com'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Turned out, it was a bug in the Ubuntu build of Chromium.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=377494) Yeah, I was using Chromium (and I use Ubuntu as my OS) That plnkr link that person provided in the issue, it didn't work in Chromium. But it worked fine in Chrome and Firefox

Tested my app too in Chrome and Firefox; works just as it did before.

Answer (score 1):

you could try adding @csrf_exempt decorator around the view that serves the response... but of course, this will disable CSRF verification...

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def your_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: I'm check if user's logged in. If not, he/she is redirected to login page. That is not csrf exempted. I did try it, but it didn't work. I'll have to exempt django login form view, but I can't do that.

Comment: hmm... well, you could completely disable CSRF verification for the whole site... as per the doc, it's not recommended but can be done... (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/)

just remove 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' from MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in the settings

Comment: IMHO, csrf exemption is a hack and not an answer to this question. And as the author mentioned it was working on public ip, but not on sub domain, the problem is something else.